# jquery to find numbers with regular expressions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a script to find numbers with in the following format `(***)***-***`
but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried finding phone numbers with only dashes and that worked but when adding the parenthesis doesn't seem to work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').html($('body').html().replace(/(\(\d\d\d\)-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)/g, '<span style="display:inline-block;">$1</span>'));
});
```

Comment: The regex looks for `(***)-***-****` and not `(***)***-***`

Comment: `(***)***-***` is different from the regex you have. Please clarify which format you are looking for exactly

Comment: thanks guys I cant believe I didnt see that, I got it all fixed now

Comment: @DanielRubio if one of these answers helped you fix your problem then you should accept it as correct.

Comment: its weird, its working but now its disabling my menu. all the links don't do anything. I'm going to have to look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find phone numbers like this `(***)***-***`, use

```
/\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{3})/g
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function replace(){    
   var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
   if( myNewTitle.length==0 ){
       alert('empty');
       return;
   }
   
   var title = document.getElementById('title');
   title.innerHTML = myNewTitle.replace(/(\(\d\d\d\)-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)/g, '###');       
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Example</h1>
<input type="text" id="myTextField" value="phone (123)-123-1234"/>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="replace()"/>
```